# Why does an inline element accept width and height when floated?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Now I have a span element I give it width and height for example 500px
I know it inline element so it doesn't accept width and height but why it applies when I float it??

```css
span.first {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: right;
}

span.second {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<span class="first">with float</span>
<span class="second">without float</span>
```

https://codepen.io/kemozzz/pen/KvVrXj

Comment: Need more info... Show a code example, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In accordance with CSS rules, when you apply float to an element, in most cases it becomes a block element. Elements that are inline and inline-block will compute to block.

**From MDN:** [image]

Answer (score 0):

When you float an element, it automatically becomes `display: block`.

*From the spec:*

[image]

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo